# a c programming question error while compiling and executing

Tags: c

I'm having an error while trying to compile and execute my code.

The source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14125365
#define MAX 180

main()
{
    int angle;
    float x,y;
    angle = 0;
    printf("Angle Cos(angle)\n");
    while(angle <= MAX)
    {
        x = (PI/MAX)*angle;
        y = cos(x);
        printf("%5d %3.4f\n", angle,y);
        angle = angle + 10;
    }
}
```

when I try to execute the above program the following error comes up

```
./math_functions.c
./math_functions.c: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `"Angle Cos(angle)\n"'
./math_functions.c: line 11: `printf("Angle Cos(angle)\n");'
```

I also get a warning message and error message after trying to compile which is as follows

```
math_functions.c:6:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 main()
 ^~~~
/tmp/ccOZSgOb.o: In function `main':
math_functions.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `cos'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Reopening.  The marked dup only addresses the first half of the question, not the second half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you're attempting to run your C source file as a shell script.  That's not how you run a C program.  You do it by first compiling the program and running the resulting executable.

The reason you're getting a compilation error is because you're using the `cos` function which resides in the math library which is not linked in by default.  You need to add `-lm` at the end of your compilation command to link that library in.

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -o math_functions math_functions.c -lm
```

Also, the reason you're getting the warning about return type defaulting to `int` is is that your main function doesn't have a specified return type. Put an int before the declaration and you'll be fine, ie

```
int main()
```